# how to put double quotes of the select output header in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

how to put double quotes on each of the header in my select output in oracle ?
because i need to export it in csv file, and I want it to be like this

e.g

```
"columnaHeader1", "columnHeader2", "columnHeader3"
"col1data1","col2data1","col3data1"
"col2data2","col2data2","col3data2"
```

because in my current query when I do like

e.g

```
case when blahblah is not null then '""' end  as "header" from tablename
```

the header is still not enclosed in double quotes..how to do that in oracle ?

Comment: You just need to `concatenate` the double quotes, no need of `CASE` and `UNION ALL`. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just concatenate double quotes, should be simple :

```
SQL> SELECT '"'||ename||'"' as "columnheader1",
  2         '"'||job||'"' as "columnheader2"
  3  FROM emp
  4  /

columnheader columnheade
------------ -----------
"SMITH"      "CLERK"
"ALLEN"      "SALESMAN"
"WARD"       "SALESMAN"
"JONES"      "MANAGER"
"MARTIN"     "SALESMAN"
"BLAKE"      "MANAGER"
"CLARK"      "MANAGER"
"SCOTT"      "ANALYST"
"KING"       "PRESIDENT"
"TURNER"     "SALESMAN"
"ADAMS"      "CLERK"
"JAMES"      "CLERK"
"FORD"       "ANALYST"
"MILLER"     "CLERK"

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

To get rid of the header from the above query, set `PAGESIZE` to zero. And to add a comma delimeter, set `COLSEP` :

```
SQL> set pagesize 0
SQL> set colsep ,
SQL> SELECT '"'||ename||'"' as "columnheader1",
  2         '"'||job||'"' as "columnheader2"
  3  FROM emp
  4  /
"SMITH"     ,"CLERK"
"ALLEN"     ,"SALESMAN"
"WARD"      ,"SALESMAN"
"JONES"     ,"MANAGER"
"MARTIN"    ,"SALESMAN"
"BLAKE"     ,"MANAGER"
"CLARK"     ,"MANAGER"
"SCOTT"     ,"ANALYST"
"KING"      ,"PRESIDENT"
"TURNER"    ,"SALESMAN"
"ADAMS"     ,"CLERK"
"JAMES"     ,"CLERK"
"FORD"      ,"ANALYST"
"MILLER"    ,"CLERK"

14 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

Referenct to [Schema Object Names and Qualifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm)

> Quoted identifiers can contain any characters and punctuations marks as well as spaces. However, neither quoted nor nonquoted identifiers can contain double quotation marks or the null character (\0)

So you have to  export header as data instead.

You could union headers from DUAL table like this:

```
select 'columnaHeader1', 'columnHeader2', 'columnHeader3' from DUAL
union all
select ...
```

Comment: i modified my question..because i wasd using a case statement

Comment: How does this answers to OP's question? OP wants double quotes in the output.

Comment: @LalitKumarB OP's question only mentioned how to double quote the header, So I think OP already know how to double quote the data.

Comment: @sasori Header is an identifier, you cannot put double quote in an identifier.